# Facing alignment issues with image elements in React-Quill within a Next.js application

Tags: javascript, next.js, quill, react-quill

Struggling with image alignment issue in react-quill while integrating with a Next.js application. Text alignment works well, but image alignment behaves unexpectedly. I'm using the following code snippet for the Quill editor:

```
const toolbarOptions = [
  [{ font: [] }],
  [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
  ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"], // toggled buttons
  ["blockquote", "code-block"],

  [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
  [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }], // superscript/subscript
  [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }], // outdent/indent
  [{ direction: "rtl" }], // text direction

  [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
  [
    {
      align: [],
    },
  ],

  ["clean"], // remove formatting button
  ["link", "image"],
];
```

```
return(
 <ReactQuill
  theme="snow"
  id={id}
  value={value}
  readOnly={disabled}
  modules={{ toolbar: disabled ? false : toolbarOptions }}
  onChange={onChange}
  className={`bg-[white] rounded-lg text-black h-96`}
  {...rest}
 />
);
```

Images aren't aligning as expected, even though text alignment works fine. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this image alignment issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

I configured the Quill editor with alignment options for images using the provided **`toolbarOptions`**. Text alignment functions correctly, but the image alignment doesn't behave as anticipated. I expected the **`align`** option to align images accordingly, but it seems to have no effect on their alignment.